# Firebase storage javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, gcloud

I'm trying to make a web application, where I wish to use Firebase storage for storing files such as images and mp3s, but I'm having some issues.

First setting up firebase. I've heard about two ways.

Gcloud:

```
let gcloud = require('gcloud')({ ... });

let storage = gcloud.storage({
    projectId: '<projectID>',
    keyFilename: 'service-account-credentials.json'
});

let bucket = storage.bucket('<projectID>.appspot.com');
```

Trouble is that I can't find the right npm install line for installing gcloud.

and firebase by config

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: ,
    authDomain: ,
    projectId: ,
    storageBucket: ,
    messagingSenderId: ,
    appId: 
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

This could easily install with npm, but I wonder if it is the right way?

Then this is set up, how do I upload and read with fetching through javascript? I'm finding it kind of difficult, so could be nice with some directions.

Comment: where do you want to start on front end or backend ?

Comment: I have a java backend with database that has endpoint values for the stored files, so it should only be frontend for storing and fetching images and mp3s.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are developing a web application you should use the Firebase JavaScript SDK (and you should not use gcloud).

The guide to use this SDK in your web application is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

Then you need to follow the [documentation for Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start), again by using the JS SDK.

Comment: Thank you, it's nice to have pointer, especially for what is useful of a web application.